# Where is seek method for FileReader of Phonegap 2.2.0?

Tags: file, cordova, filereader, seek, random-access

I need a method like [FileWriter.seek(offset)](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter) for FileReader.

I searched a lot but didn't found any thing?
It is so strange for me that FileWriter has seek method, but FileReader does not have it!
I wanna read the 1MB within a 100MB file. I really don't wanna load the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no seek method for the FileReader. It is not part of the W3C specification for the FileReader interface.

**Update:** As of PhoneGap 2.4.0 the File.slice() method will be implemented so you should pretty much get what you want from that.

Comment: @Simon> Is any specific PhoneGAP API or plugin exists for read and seek into file?